# Add user to MongoDB with Mongoose

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

New to noSQL databases, and still trying to wrap my head around them.

I'm using Node, Express, and MongoDB with Mongoose to build a simple CMS for a single user (hence no need for web user registration) to add/update pages.

I have the User modelled with Mongoose as follows:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var adminUser = new Schema({
        username: String,
        password: String
    });
    var adminUser = mongoose.model('adminUser', adminUser);
module.exports=adminUser;
```

And the page as follows:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    var Page = new Schema({
        title: String,
        url: {type:String, index:{unique:true}},
        content: String,
        menuIndex: Number,
        date: Date    });
    var Page = mongoose.model('Page', Page);
    module.exports=Page;
```

And I'm able to access the Mongo shell and add pages from there.

I guess my real issue is I'm not sure whether I should create another collection for Users within my application database, or add a user to the database itself. What is the best way to add a User here that preserves a one-to-many relationship between User and Page without creating a web user registration.

I'm new to JS from a RoR background, so I'm guess I'm looking for something roughly equivalent to opening up the rails console and creating an instance of a modelled User through ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 0):

you have to maintain two different collections and use the reference key page collection

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    var Page = new Schema({
userid: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'adminUser'}, // reference to use schema 
        title: String,
        url: {type:String, index:{unique:true}},
        content: String,
        menuIndex: Number,
        date: Date    });
    var Page = mongoose.model('Page', Page);
    module.exports=Page;
```